# Convert short (8.3) paths to long?

Tags: winapi, wtl

In a Win32/WTL/C++ app, I need to convert some 8.3 paths to their true file names.  How do I do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [GetLongPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364980(VS.85).aspx)  API.